# shiny - how to disable the dashboardHeader

Tags: shiny, dashboard

I am new to shiny. When I made my project, I need to hide the dashboardHeader in server side.

In the shinydashboard website, I found the code `dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE)`. I tried this, but it was not work.

However, I tried use shinyjs to solve the problem.

```
    <code>

    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(shinyjs)

    ui <- dashboardPage(
          dashboardHeader(
                extendShinyjs(text = 'shinyjs.hidehead = function(params) {           
                $("header").addClass("sidebar-collapse") }'),
                          ),
          dashboardSidebar(),
          dashboardBody(
              actionButton("button","hide_header",width = 4 )
                       )
                       )

    server <- function(input, output) {
         observeEvent(input$button, {
                       js$hidehead()           
                  })}

   shinyApp(ui, server)</code>
```

I guess you already known, it still not worked.

Any ideas for my case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shinyjs is a great library. The problem with your code is that you need first to initialize `shinyjs` with `shinyjs::useShinyjs()` and put it inside the `dashboarBody` function. Also, to hide/show the header you don't need to add the class `"sidebar-collapse"` that is actually for the sidebar. You only need to add `style="display:none"` to hide the header, and remove it to show the header. Below is your code modified to hide/show the header. The JS code used is very simple and it receive the parameter to add directly from the `js$hidehead()` function.

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(),
        dashboardSidebar(),
        dashboardBody(
          # initialize shinyjs
          shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
          # add custom JS code
          extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.hidehead = function(parm){
                                    $('header').css('display', parm);
                                }"),
          actionButton("button","hide header"),
          actionButton("button2","show header")
        )
      )

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    js$hidehead('none')           
  })
  observeEvent(input$button2, {
    js$hidehead('')           
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Can not thanks more.  I  screw up the sidebar and header.   Your answer helps me understand the shinyjs function. Really appreciate your help. Thanks Again.

Comment: Good to know that it help you. If it is a good answer for your question, you can accept the question with the check mark, so you can help other users.